# Best approach to set up this database model (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, database, model, relational-database

I'm looking to set up a blog database on my website. I'm setting up a MySQL database with a **posts** table with the attributes: **post_id, datetime, content** (all pretty self-explanatory). I want each post to have tags (which can be any number of tags). Obviously, this needs a table on its own, so I made a **tags** table with attributes: **tag_id, tag_name**. Now, to link them I guess I should make a third table, called **post_tag** which will define links between posts and tags, so it will have attributes: **post_id, tag_id**. I'm sort of new to database structuring, so I'm wondering if I'm doing this the right way, or if there is perhaps a more efficient way at tackling this problem?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If posts can have multiple tags you should have 3 tables:

> posts: post_id,postname ........
>
> tags: tag_id,tag_name
>
> post-tags (linked table) post_id,tag_id

This may be interested for you:
http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm